# Weird behaviour of JodaTime in different environments

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I'm using JodaTime's DateTimeFormat to represent some dates in my REST API.

The format I'm using is

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("EST"));
```

So I want my dates to be represented as, for example: 04/14/2016 08:50:31 EST

The problem is that when I run my code in Production it works well (the date is represented like the example above), but when I run it in my local machine or in staging, it represents it like:

04/14/2016 09:05:53 -05:00

I'm using the exact same code in both environments. Also, both Staging and Production are running in Amazon, and have the server date set equally, so I don't know how to solve this issue.

I have made a simple Main to illustrate and reproduce my problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
                .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));
        System.out.println(new DateTime(new Date()).toString(format));
}
```

P.S. I'm using Java 8 and JodaTime 2.7

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are not using a capital Z in the format of your local test? Because I can't replicate your output with the given example.

Comment: I'm 100% confident on that. I'm using JodaTime 2.7

Comment: Is updating joda an option for you? I ve just tried with 2.7 and it indeed doesn't work. Previously with 2.9.3 I couldn't replicate.

Comment: With JodaTIme 2.9.3 it worked. What seems weird is that it works well in Production with 2.7. I will be changing it to 2.9.3 and see if it works in both environments. Thanks!

Comment: @SantiagoIgnacioPoli  When you verify, please post and accept an Answer here to close this Question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by upgrading to Joda Time 2.9.3 as suggested by @dambros. What seems weird is that it worked in Production with 2.7, but that's a problem for another day.

Thanks!